# How to repeat part of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a loop for part of my JavaScript code, I tried several methods, but they only return `i=0` , my js code is

```
    function format ( a ) {
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i <a.hr.length; i++) {

    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">'+
    '<thead>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th data-sortable="true">Full name:</th>'+
            '<th>Extension number:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].salary+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].start_date+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</tbody>'+
    '</table>';
    }
}
```

also I try:

```
            function format ( a ) {
        var i;
        
        for (i = 0; i <a.hr.length; i++) {
    
        return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">'+
        '<thead>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<th data-sortable="true">Full name:</th>'+
                '<th>Extension number:</th>'+
                '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
                '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
for (i = 0; i <a.hre.length; i++) {
            '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].salary+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].start_date+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
}
        '</tbody>'+
        '</table>';
        
    }
```

both methods return just i=0 , even I use `for (i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {` but still I get i=0. Would you please give me some tips in order to solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide value of a

Comment: I use datatables.net and just a parameter to collect the key in JSON file. and it can be anything. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `return` from the function in the for loop, so it never gets to the second iteration..
Try creating a variable outside the loop, appending to it in the loop and returning after:

```
function format ( a ) {
    var i;
    let res = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">'+
    '<thead>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th data-sortable="true">Full name:</th>'+
            '<th>Extension number:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>';

    for (i = 0; i <a.hr.length; i++) {
        res +=
        '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].salary+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].start_date+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    
    }
    res += '</tbody>'+
    '</table>';
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is use `map` instead of for-loop.

```js
function format(a) {
      return a.hr.map(val => 
    
       '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">'+
        '<thead>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<th data-sortable="true">Full name:</th>'+
                '<th>Extension number:</th>'+
                '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
                '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+val.position+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+val.salary+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+val.start_date+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+val.position+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</tbody>'+
        '</table>');     
}

const a = {
hr: [{position: 2, salary: 2000, start_date: '10/10/2020'},{position: 2, salary: 2000, start_date: '10/09/2020' }]
}
        
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = format(a).join('');
```

```html
<div id='root'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks UKS, I use datatables.net and I had to use `function format ( a ) {}`, I just need to repeat <tr> and I can not remove `function format ( a ) {}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use a `return` in the middle of your loop and this means your loop access the first element only. To solve this you can do the following:

```
function format ( a ) { 
    var i, result = ''; 
    for (i = 0; i <a.hr.length; i++) { 
        result += '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"  bo'...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want. Use string concatenation, until all your HTML is formed, then return the final HTML string.

```
function format ( a ) {
    var str = "";

    for (var i = 0; i <a.hr.length; i++) {
      str += '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">'+
        '<thead>'+
          '<tr>'+
            '<th data-sortable="true">Full name:</th>'+
            '<th>Extension number:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
            '<th>Extra info:</th>'+
          '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
          '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].salary+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].start_date+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+a.hr[i].position+'</td>'+
          '</tr>'+
        '</tbody>'+
      '</table>';
    }

    return str;
}
```

**NOTE:** If you `return` inside the loop, then it will only run once in your case, because that will be considered as return value of enclosing function.